# Can my identity be revealed through WiFi access?

Tags: wifi

Assuming I am using a WiFi connection on my Android phone, can somebody also on the network know the particular sites I visit?

I believe they will get to know my MAC ID, but will they get to know other things through my phone that could identify me?

Comment: Your identity is always in your hand. Whenever it gets revealed you are the culprit. Yes, your identity can be revealed. For example if some one is sniffing the network and you are browsing the internet with unencrypted connection. Then the attacker can see what you are visiting. Also the attacker can see what data you are sending and receiving. For eg: assuming that you are using an unencrypted chatting service with someone who is close to you(friend, girl friend), now in this case the attacker might see your names in the chat.

Comment: The attacker might see everything you discuss in your chat. So now if you discuss about your home address or credit card details, then you can imagine what could happen later. This is just an example. Also, this method will work for any device computers, iPads, mobile etc. Regarding the MAC ID other answers have already explained them below.

Answer (score 3):

Knowing your identity, John Doe, and your device information are two separate things. They will likely know your IP address (that was assigned you), and your device/MAC address but that doesn't necessarily translate to John Doe unless there is some other information to connect the dots.

If you are connecting to a wifi that you had to sign up for (and say, accept a Terms of Service), then there will likely be a log in their system of who you said you were when you signed up and will tie that back to the IP address that was assigned your device when you connected.

That's not to say that there aren't ways of correlating & collecting more info that would aid in determining identity but we don't know enough about the network in question to say.